# Instagram Client ID

Tags: api, instagram

I'm looking to get an instagram client ID to integrate with our website but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards

Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

You have to register on https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/ to create a developer API/Account. You can create API Credentials like your Client-ID there. Its not possible with just a "normal user account".